# Dividir campo en varios campos por un separador

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, estoy iniciando en SQL y tengo el siguiente caso para ver si me pueden apoyar.

Tengo un campo con información dividida por pipes que quisiera separar en varias  columnas, por ejemplo el campo se ve de la siguiente manera

```
359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3
```

Quisiera tener 5 columnas separando la información.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentas algo, por ejemplo alguna clase de substring o split?

Comment: No olvides incluir entre los tags el del motor de base de datos que estás utilizando. Un saludo.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689072/5215609

Answer (score 5):

En SQL Server te puedes valer de la función [`charindex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para ir determinando la posición de cada uno de los separadores, en este caso el caracter `'|'`.

Una vez tienes la posición de cada uno de los separadores, puedes utilizar la función [`substring`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para *extraer* las sub-cadenas en cada columna.

Para que el código sea fácil de entender, sugiero utilizar un CTE primero, para determinar únicamente las posiciones de los separadores, y luego en la consulta final utilizar estas posiciones para extraer cada segmento.

En código, separar en 5 columnas sería esto:

```
with 
Datos as (
select '359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3' Dato
union all select 'A|B|C|D|E'
union all select 'AA|BB|CC|DD|EE'
union all select 'AAAAAAA|BB|CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC|DDDDDD|EEEEEEEEEEE'
--      123456789012345678901234567890
)
,
CalculoIndices as (
select   Dato
       , CHARINDEX('|', Dato) idx1
       , CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato) + 1) idx2
       , CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato) + 1) + 1) idx3
       , CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato, CHARINDEX('|', Dato) + 1) + 1) + 1) idx4
  from Datos
)
select a.Dato
       , SUBSTRING(a.Dato, 1, idx1 - 1) Dato1
       , SUBSTRING(a.Dato, idx1 + 1, idx2 - idx1 - 1) Dato2
       , SUBSTRING(a.Dato, idx2 + 1, idx3 - idx2 - 1) Dato3
       , SUBSTRING(a.Dato, idx3 + 1, idx4 - idx3 - 1) Dato4
       , SUBSTRING(a.Dato, idx4 + 1, 1000) Dato5
  from CalculoIndices a
```

Lo cual arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Dato                                          Dato1    Dato2  Dato3            Dato4   Dato5
--------------------------------------------- -------- ------ ---------------- ------- ------------
359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3                359801   NUEVO  123451           TALLAG  1.3
A|B|C|D|E                                     A        B      C                D       E
AA|BB|CC|DD|EE                                AA       BB     CC               DD      EE
AAAAAAA|BB|CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC|DDDDDD|EEEEEEEEEEE AAAAAAA  BB     CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  DDDDDD  EEEEEEEEEEE

(4 rows affected)
```

El *truco* está en utilizar la posición del elemento anterior como parámetro a la siguiente llamada de `charindex`.

He incluido en el CTE de simulación de tu tabla de datos algunas filas adicionales para que se pueda apreciar el correcto funcionamiento en los resultados.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma interesante es procesar la columna original para generar un  `xml` dónde etiquetamos cada una de las 5 columnas con el tag `<columna>..</columna>` para luego simplemente acceder `xmlname.value()` al valor de la misma y así conformar las 5 columnas definitivas.

```
;WITH Split
AS
(
    SELECT  VALOR,
        CONVERT(XML,'<columnas><columna>' + REPLACE(VALOR,'|', '</columna><columna>') + '</columna></columnas>') AS xmlname
    FROM (  
        -- Tabla desde donde buscamos la columna a dividir
        SELECT '359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3' AS 'VALOR' UNION
        SELECT '359802|VIEJO|525512|TALLAXL|3.3' AS 'VALOR'

    ) T
)  
SELECT  Valor,      
    xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/columna[1]','varchar(100)') AS V1,    
    xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/columna[2]','varchar(100)') AS V2,
    xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/columna[3]','varchar(100)') AS V3,    
    xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/columna[4]','varchar(100)') AS V4,
    xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/columna[5]','varchar(100)') AS V5   
    FROM Split

╔═════════════════════════════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ Valor                           ║ V1     ║ V2    ║ V3     ║ V4      ║ V5  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3  ║ 359801 ║ NUEVO ║ 123451 ║ TALLAG  ║ 1.3 ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ 359802|VIEJO|525512|TALLAXL|3.3 ║ 359802 ║ VIEJO ║ 525512 ║ TALLAXL ║ 3.3 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

fuente: [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/6836377)

Answer (score 2):

Una de las funciones más rápidas para dividir cadenas delimitadas fue creada por Eirikur Eirikson basándose en el gran trabajo de Jeff Moden. La función está explicada en [este artículo en inglés](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) y es la siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]  
--===== Define I/O parameters  
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS  
 RETURN  
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...  
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)  
 WITH E1(N) AS (  
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1  
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows  
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows  
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max  
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front  
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"  
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  
                ),  
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)  
                 SELECT t.N+1  
                   FROM cteTally t  
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)   
                )  
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.  
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),  
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))  
   FROM cteStart s  
;
```

Teniendo esta función, sólo tenemos que pivotear los datos. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
--Crear datos de prueba
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE(
    ColDelimitada   varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO @Tabla VALUES( '359801|NUEVO|123451|TALLAG|1.3')

--Aplicar la función
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 1 THEN s.Item END) AS Col1,
        MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 2 THEN s.Item END) AS Col2,
        MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 3 THEN s.Item END) AS Col3,
        MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 4 THEN s.Item END) AS Col4,
        MAX( CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 5 THEN s.Item END) AS Col5
FROM @Tabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD( t.ColDelimitada, '|') s
GROUP BY t.ColDelimitada;
```

Tengo entendido que es más eficiente hacerlo con las nuevas funciones para manejar JSON, pero es algo que no he probado por la falta de un ambiente adecuado.